# Java Swing Applet- Cant set background color

Tags: java, swing, applet

Im new to Swing, first of all. Im trying to set the background color of an audio recording applet to make it blend with my webpage (white instead of the default grey), but the change never seems to take. Heres the applet initialization...

```
public void init()
{
    setLayout(null);
    setBackground(Color.white);
    JLabel recorder = new JLabel("Record");
    JLabel fileName = new JLabel("Please Enter File Name");
    JLabel status = new JLabel("Status...");
    fnametxt = new JTextField("FileNameHere");
    statustxt = new JTextField("");
    record = new JButton("Record");
    play = new JButton("Play");
    pause = new JButton("Pause");
    stop = new JButton("Stop");
    send = new JButton("Upload");
    listen = new JButton("Listen");
    save = new JButton("Save and Submit");
//A bunch of other stuff, event listeners and whatnot.
```

Im using no layout managers, Im setting all the positions manually. Any ideas?

Comment: what `Container` are you adding your `JButton` and `JTextField` objects to?  Have you tried setting the background color on that container?

Comment: First write `setOpaque(true)`, then, instead of using `setBackground(...)`, try `getContentPane().setBackground(...)`, that might can solve the thingy for you, if you not using any `JPanel` to hold your components that you had shown.

Comment: The setOpaque doesnt work, it says there is no setOpaque method for type AudioApplet(Which extends JApplet)

Comment: Hwowever, coloring the content pane did work, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably should set the background color of the content pane.

Answer (score 6):

You set (presumably) the background of the Applet, but that background will only show where it is not obstructed by another component.

Depending on how you structured your GUI, there may be inner panels or other components covering the area. You need to change the color of those components, too (or alternately set them to be transparent using setOpaque(false)).

Edit: setOpaque() is only available for Swing components, not the Applet itself (since that is plain old AWT).

Comment: I dont have any other panels or containers that I can see. When i add the components (buttons and such), I just set the bouns (button.setBounds(x,x,x,x)) of each one and then add(button).

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a JPanel in your applet, you'll have to color the JPanel's content pane as well. The following code sets the background of the JPanel itself AND its content pane to white:

```
setBackground(Color.white);
getContentPane().setBackground(Color.white); //Color JPanel
```

Comment: this question is correctly ansered. your question can be deleted by community (users here)